# Elastic search exception on parsing date

Tags: date, parsing, exception, elasticsearch

I am getting the following exception:

```
ElasticsearchParseException[failed to parse date field [2016-02-20T22:00:00.000Z], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Invalid format: \"2016-02-20T22:00:00.000Z\"]
```

On the following query:

```
curl -XGET https://xxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/yyy/zzz/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "event_timestamp": {
                                    "gte": "‌2016-02-20T22:00:00.000Z",
                                    "lte": "‌2016-02-27T22:00:00.000Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

event_timestamp is mapped as:

```
"event_timestamp":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"}
```

And a sample entry is:

```
{
      "_index" : "yyy",
      "_type" : "zzz",
      "_id" : "abcde",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"event":"xxx","client_timestamp":"1456347863865","event_timestamp":"2016-02-24T21:04:23.495Z","partitionKey":"xxx"}
```

Comment: `dateOptionalTime` is your custom format??

Comment: actually i did not specify it, that's what kibana put in when i selected this field for the time based index as the so called "Time-field name"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the time in milli as that's the only format ES is willing to accept in this specific scenario as it seems.

If anyone has any suggestions I'm open to hear alternatives.

So this did work:

```
curl -XGET https://xxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/yyy/zzz/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "event_timestamp": {
                                     "gte": 1456005600000,
                                     "lte": 1456610400000
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```